# Meteor Collection returns none when deployed on production

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I'm working on a Meteor application that has a slider (revolution slider plugin to be exact) on the homepage. I have a template helper that pulls the images on the collection. It works perfect locally, but when deployed on Meteor's free server, it returns nothing from the collection.

Also, I tried using the imagesLoaded plugin to check if all images loaded before running the script to trigger the slider, however, still it does not work. I've checked the developer tools and found out that it did not load at all. The 'sliders' helper returns nothing.

What do you think might be the problem. I have been solving this issue for quite some time now and I run out of options.

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

By the way, here's my code for the helper:

```
Template.homepageSlider.helpers({
    sliders: function() {
        return _.map(HomepageSliders.find({}, {fields: {url:1, client_name:1}}).fetch(), function(val, index) {
            return {value: val, active: (index == 0 ? "item active" : "item")} 
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<!-- SLIDE -->
           {{#each sliders}}  
            <li class="revolution-mch-1" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="3" data-masterspeed="1000" data-title="{{this.value.client_name}}">
                <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                <img id="homepage-img" src="{{this.value.url}}"  alt="darkblurbg"  data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="left top" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                <div class="tp-caption finewide_verysmall_white_mw sft start"
                    data-x="left"
                    data-hoffset="50"
                    data-y="bottom"
                    data-voffset="-35"
                    data-speed="1500"
                    data-start="100"
                    data-easing="Back.easeInOut"
                    data-endeasing="Power1.easeIn"                        
                    data-endspeed="300">
                    <i class="fa fa-info"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{this.value.client_name}}
                </div>
            </li>
            {{/each}}
            <!-- END SLIDE -->
```

Comment: Do the physical image files even exist on the free Meteor server? And when you say `pulls the images on the collection` do you mean that the image data is actually being stored in Mongo via `CollectionFS` or `GridFS` or something?

Comment: How can I check if it's physically exist on the server? The logo and other images works fine and since it's on the same folder, I guess it do exist in the server. Also, in Mongo, it only stores the image path (i.e, '/img/sliders/). Do you think that's the problem?

Comment: Give us the link to your website.

Comment: Hi all, was able to fix the issue by using iron-router's waitOn functionality to subscribe on the collection.